# Persist Dynamic form fields in ant design step component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm have a multi step form using the ant design step component to achieve this. In one of the steps, I have an implementation of a dynamic input field addition where I click a "plus" sign to add a new field. Once completed and I skip to the next step and come back to the step, only one field is present and when I click on the "plus" sign again to add fields as before, it adds the fields but they already have the data previous entered.

How do I persist such that if I leave that step and come back, the number of fields I leave is the same number I meet when I come back?

```js
const { field, dynamicFields } = inputs; //coming from props

const [blankField, setBlankField] = useState([dynamicFields]);

const addField = () => {
  setBlankField([...blankField, [...dynamicFields]]);
};

{
  blankField.map((items, legId) => (
    <>
      {legId !== 0 ? (
        <Divider orientation="left">{`${LEG}${legId}`}</Divider>
      ) : (
        false
      )}
      {items.map(item => {
        const { placeholder, key, label, inputType, rules, options } = item;
        const totalOptions = { preserve: true, rules, ...options };

        return (
          <Form.Item {...DYNAMIC_FORM_ITEM_LAYOUT} key={legId} label={label}>
            {getFieldDecorator(
              `${field}[${legId}].${key}`,
              totalOptions
            )(
              <Select
                allowClear
                showSearch
                onSearch={onSearch}
                placeholder={intl.formatMessage(placeholder)}
                loading={isLoading}
              >
                {predictions
                  ? predictions.map(({ description, id }) => (
                      <Option key={id} value={description}>
                        {description}
                      </Option>
                    ))
                  : false}
              </Select>
            )}
          </Form.Item>
        );
      })}
    </>
  ));
}
```

I'd like to add that when the step is complete and I submit, all the values from all the fields are saved appropriately. What I just need to be able to do is persist the fields with their values intact so when I move to the next step and come back, I see it the way I left it.

Video Link to help understand my problem - [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iq3TO0PUrVfjN8agqHrNi1xxBIRxUPon/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you create a code sandbox?

Comment: I can't cos there are a lot of dependent files. What I can do is share a link to a video so you can get into perspective @blueseal cool?

Comment: @blueseal - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Iq3TO0PUrVfjN8agqHrNi1xxBIRxUPon/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `redux` for retaining and managing states , if you haven't used redux in this project.

Comment: @blueseal I am using redux. That's how I get the values saved. **I would just like the fields to persist in the view**. Only the values and the keys get saved in my store.